# Silverstripe autocomplete textfield

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I used [tractorcow's Silverstripe-autocomplete](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-autocomplete) module on a website to implement autocomplete feature on a textfield. However, I wonder why it returns the ID field instead of text(on CompanyName field).

[image]

Here's the code.

On my page I used it on a form as:

```
public function MyForm(){
$fields = FieldList::create();
...
$fields->push(AutoCompleteField::create('StudentGroup_Name', 'Company name *','',null,null,'UserCompany','CompanyName')->setAttribute('required','required'));
...

}
```

then, my dataobject is as follows:

```
class UserCompany extends DataObject{

  private static $db = [
    'CompanyID'      =>  'Int',
    'CompanyName'    =>  'Varchar(512)'
  ];

  private static $summary_fields = [
    'CompanyID'       =>  'CompanyID',
    'CompanyName'     =>  'CompanyName'
  ];

  private static $default_sort = 'CompanyName ASC';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked out the source code and the default `displayField` is `Title`. You can either change your `UserCompany` object by changing the `CompanyName` field to `Title` or use the `setDisplayField` method.

```
$fields->push(AutoCompleteField::create('StudentGroup_Name', 'Company name *','',null,null,'UserCompany','CompanyName')->setDisplayField('CompanyName')->setAttribute('required','required'));
```

**Edit**

Using a setter function for `Title` should work also. That means you don't need to use setDisplayField.

```
class UserCompany extends DataObject {
  ...

  function Title() {
    return $this->CompanyName;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gavin this is what's causing it but changing the CompanyName column might be confusing since we're using it as header to import CSV data. What I did was to change the __construct() method and set the fields to the $sourceFields by checking its count. This way, I could also reuse the class on my other dataobjects.         

      if(count($this->sourceFields) == 1){
        $this->displayField = $this->sourceFields[0];
        ...
      }